# How do I solve addPerCellQC error that states sce is not numeric?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I'm working in R analysing single cell RNA seq data. I'm currently trying to add QC data to my SingleCellExperiment (sce) object; mito_genes, ribo_genes and ERCC_genes contain the row locations of those particular genes as performed by

```
mito_genes <- grep("^mt-", rownames(sce))

ribo_genes <- grep("^Rp[ls]", rownames(sce))

ERCC_genes <- grep("^ERCC-", rownames(sce))
```

Code to add the QC data to colData

```
sce <- addPerCellQC(sce, subsets=list(Mito = mito_genes, Ribo = ribo_genes, ERCC = ERCC_genes))
colData(sce)
```

The error I'm getting: `Error in base::colSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) :  'x' must be numeric`

Seems to me like there may be something wrong with sce itself, as perCellQCMetrics(sce) returns the same error. I had previously generated the sce and attached Indexsort data to an alternative experiment. I haven't however had this error before. I've tried reloading everything, etc.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was an omitted non-numerical column that was left in my index sort matrix, which then led to the sce object being identified as non-numerical.